# Parse Google Calculator with Json in Windows Phone 7 / C#?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, windows-phone-7

I'm currently making an application for WP7 where I'm implementing a currency exchange solution. I could make it with CSV too, but every time I find a snippet which looks alright (and modify it, etc.), I just meet limitations from the C# Silverlight libraries.

So basically, I'm now trying to filter out necessary information from the Google Calculator JSON result.

Basically this is the link: [Google Calculator](http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=10USD=?DKK)
And this is the result of the JSON: `{lhs: "10 U.S. dollars",rhs: "54.2090627 Danish kroner",error: "",icc: true}`

Now, if I would like a textBlock to show "10 U.S. Dollars = 54.20 Danish Kroner", how would I have to parse and filter this? I would basically only need the application to go to the website on the click of a button, fetch the information, and return the result formated like above!

Comment: You are asking several questions here. You should focus your question to one question, presumably your title question.

Comment: Where are you having trouble -- is it parsing the JSON, or extracting the numbers from the string values? If the former, there are several JSON libraries in C# you can try.

Comment: Thank you, I will try out the libraries. I've been trying out several methods till now, but neither parsing it, nor extracting anything has worked as I thought. Will try more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy. I will illustrate making the call to the REST service and parsing the JSON data into a class. Then I think you'll be able to do the string concatenation and display on your own.

Start by adding a reference to the System.ServiceModel.Web assembly, which will give you access to the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) in the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace.

Next, create a class to represent the JSON. Use auto-implemented properties whose names match the JSON returned by the service:

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
  public string lhs { get; set; }
  public string rhs { get; set; }
  public string error { get; set; }
  public string icc { get; set; }
}
```

I'll assume you want to get the data when a button is clicked, so here's a small app with a button click handler.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace WP7JsonClient
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
      var client = new WebClient();

      // Callback function written in-line as a lambda statement
      client.OpenReadCompleted +=
        ( s, eargs ) =>
        {
          var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( typeof( ExchangeRate ) );
          var exchangeRate = (ExchangeRate)serializer.ReadObject( eargs.Result );

          // display exchange rate data here...
        };

      var uri = new Uri( "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=10USD=?DKK" );
      client.OpenReadAsync( uri );
    }
  }
}
```

I've written the async callback method in-line as a lambda statement, but you could just as easily write that as a separate method. After the call to have the serializer read the object, the JSON data is now available as an instance of your JSON serialization class (ExchangeRate) so you can work with that object directly, perform data-binding with its properties, and so on.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I|ll try to get this one working instead. Shouldn`t be too much work getting the exchange rate data to be printed :) However, is there a way to limit the amount of decimals, to "XX.XX" or similar? :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a bunch. After a week of trying XML/CSV +++, I finally got json working instead! Thanks again :)! -

Comment: @AndrewB, First divide the string up into parts, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx for options. Then take the string part that is a number and make that into a decimal value using Decimal.TryParse or Decimal.Parse. Finally, when you format the decimal value for display, using string.Format, use a standard format string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to indicate how you want the value formatted, including number of digits after the decimal point. There are countless examples of string formatting available online.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out your methods. I tried to use the .Remove way of formating/modifying the text, but if there are sudden (and "extreme") changes in the currency market, the .Remove will probably ruin it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the WindowsPhone build of [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/74287). [The documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) should be enough to help you figure out how to get the information you need from there.

Comment: I'll try out the JSON.NET library now. It seems like what I would need for this! Thank you. Will report back if something is very unclear here :)

Comment: The JSON.NET library is nice, I've used it on a number of projects. Not to take anything away from that library... it's just that you don't *need* to use it for this simple scenario. I show how to use the .NET Framework's DataContractJsonSerializer to do the deserialization from JSON to a .NET class in a separate answer.