# WP7 Json serializer doesn't handle "space"?

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, xaml, windows-phone-7

I recently [made a post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002922/parse-google-calculator-with-json-in-windows-phone-7-c) (which is now marked as "answered" - which it is) about parsing Google Calc json strings into WP7 http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100GBP=?SEK.

It's working great - unless Google returns a number above 999. A number above 999 is writenn **1 000**, instead of **1000**. It seems like the "space" makes the application crash/try-catch aware that there's something wrong.

I just wonder how I can make the json serializer (using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;) (using StringBuilder) return sum/amount(s) above 999, without crashing?

Thanks :)

CODE:

Hello! I'm mainly using the code found here: [Parse Google Calculator with Json in Windows Phone 7 / C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002922/parse-google-calculator-with-json-in-windows-phone-7-c)

In order to get currency landcodes from listbox, I use:

```
        ListBoxItem toExchangeSelected= toCurrencyList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.toCurrencyListtaListe.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
        string toCurrency = toCurrencyList.Content.ToString();
        ListBoxItem fromExchangeSelected= fromCurrencyList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.fromCurrencyList.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
        string fromCurrency = fromExchangeSelected.Content.ToString();
```

Comment: One observation is that this is no ordinary 0x20 space. So there might be an encoding issue. The sequence is `c2 a0` which is UTF-8 for U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem (even when \u00A0 is used as the space).  Show the exact code that __you__ are really using that fails along with the actual exception message and indicate the line of code that is throwing the exception.  (I'll make a prediction: its actually failing where you are attempting to convert some of the string to a numeric type).

Comment: Have you tried using another parser such as json.net? If it really us a parsing issue and not a conversion issue, try json.net.

Answer (score 1):

Certain European cultures use spaces instead of commas for large numbers, so try using the appropriate CultureInfo before you parse the string:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
double d = double.Parse("1 000", ci); // returns 1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the newtonsoft json serializer. 
http://json.codeplex.com/
They have a binaries for wp7, and is better that the datacontractserializer (in my view)

I've just noticed that the second answer of your mentionned question on StackOverflow is the same as the one i'm talking about.

Use `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>(string json)` with T as your result (ExchangeRate ?)

Comment: So there's no better way to do this than using Newtonsoft's?